# How to search for a particular word in only .csv files using Linux command line?

Tags: linux

I have a directory with multiple levels of sub-directories. These sub-directories contain a combination of .avi, .txt and .csv files.

I want to be able to search through all the .csv files for a particular word. Right now I am using the following command: `grep -r "word" *`

This also searches through the .avi and .txt files. How do I limit the search to just .csv files?

Apologies if this question has been asked before, I was not able to find it.

Comment: how about `grep -r "word" *.csv` ? Good luck.

Comment: This gives me the following error: grep: *.csv: No such file or directory

Comment: and what does `ls -l *.csv` return?

Answer (score 4):

The solution which worked for me was:
`find . -type f -iname "*.csv" -print0 | xargs -0 grep "word"`

Reference: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42407/pipe-find-into-grep-v

Further, if you want to count the number of "words" in each .csv file, use: `find . -type f -iname "*.csv" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -c "word"`

If you want to count the total number of times "word" appears in all .csv files in a directory, use: `find . -type f -iname "*.csv" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -o "word" * | wc -l`

Answer (score 1):

you can find all csv file and then grep only in founded files:

```
find <your directory path> -name "*.csv" -type f | xargs grep "word"
```

Comment: This gives me the error "find: unknown predicate `-file'"

Comment: Try this:

    find <your directory path> -name "*.csv" -type f | xargs grep "word"

Comment: it was misprint. you should change -file to -name

Answer (score -1):

`grep` has an option `--include` which will filter for file name patterns.

So:

```
grep -r --include="*.jl" flue
```

finds, recursively, all Julia files containing the word "flue".